# django model query back reference filter confusion

Tags: django, model

Given the following models

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Business(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="businesses")

class Package(models.Model):
  business_id = models.ForeignKey(Business)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have 2 following queries get list of business and categories which the packages are live:

```
filter_businesses = Business.objects.filter(package__status = 'live')
filter_categories = Category.objects.filter(businesses__package__status = 'live')
```

Now the questions is, given the related name "businesses" should be equals to category.business_set, why shouldn't the filter in first query be package_set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two related models: `SomeModel` and `SomeOtherModel`, and `SomeOtherModel.somemodel` is a ForeignKey to `SomeModel`.

Given any `SomeModel` instance, the `someothermodel_set` property is a manager for the related model already filtered. For example:

```
>>> your_some_model_instance = SomeModel.objects.all()[0]
```

In this case `your_some_model_instance.shomeothermodel_set` is equivalent to:

```
>>> SomeOtherModel.objects.filter(somemodel=your_some_model_instance)
```

[ update ]

> sorry perhaps I didn't explain my questions more clearer, it's complicated to explain... I understand that XX_set and related_name refer to the manager, what I want to ask is in the first query why not use (package_set_*status = 'live') given the second working query (businesses*_package__status = 'live'), it's confusing because the second query references to the manager(by related_name), but the first query is not...

The filter interface uses the convention relatedmodelname__relatedmodelfield; In your example, related_name was used to give a fancier name to the backreference, but this is not its main purpose; the purpose of the related_name parameter in ForeignKey fields is solving the ambiguity in cases where relatedmodelname clashes with an already existing field at the ForeignKey.

Comment: Close. You mean `..._set.all()` on that last one.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: you are right, `..._set` is a manager (like `SomeModel.objects`), not a queryset - details omitted for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: sorry perhaps I didn't explain my questions more clearer, it's complicated to explain... I understand that XX_set and related_name refer to the manager, what I want to ask is in the first query why not use (package_set__status = 'live') given the second working query (businesses__package__status = 'live'), it's confusing because the second query references to the manager(by related_name), but the first query is not...